# Return file from service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have service with subscriptions, and I call it on Init and on destroy

Here is service

```
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ScreenshotService {
  private subscriptionsStack: { (file: File): any }[] = [];

  public subscribePaste(callback: (fle: File) => any) {
    if (this.subscriptionsStack.length == 0) {
      this.registerPaste();
    }

    this.subscriptionsStack.push(callback);
  }

  public unsubscribePaste(callback: (fle: File) => any) {
    const index = this.subscriptionsStack.indexOf(callback);
    this.subscriptionsStack.splice(index, 1);

    if (this.subscriptionsStack.length == 0) {
      this.unregisterPaste();
    }
  }

  // TODO: made public to pin existing behavior of the service
  public registerPaste() {
    document.addEventListener('paste', this.onPaste);
  }

  public unregisterPaste() {
    document.removeEventListener('paste', this.onPaste);
  }

  private onPaste = (event: ClipboardEvent | any): void => {
    if (this.subscriptionsStack.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    const items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    let blob: File = null;
    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
        blob = item.getAsFile();
      }
    }

    if (blob !== null) {
      const last = this.subscriptionsStack[this.subscriptionsStack.length - 1];
      last(blob);
    }
  };

  public fileToBase64(file: File): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is how I I use it in component

```
 export class SdTicketAddAttachmentsPopupComponent extends DialogBaseComponent implements OnInit {
  // public changingFiles: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  public override params!: { attachmentRestrictions: FileRestrictions; required: boolean };

  public required!: boolean;
  public attachmentRestrictions!: FileRestrictions;

  public attachmentControl: UploadFileControl;
  public label: string = 'Attachments';
  public files: File[] = [];

  public get isFormValid(): boolean {
    return this.attachmentControl.valid;
  }

  public get validationLabel(): string {
    return this.attachmentControl.errors && Object.values(this.attachmentControl.errors)[0];
  }

  constructor(
    dialog: DialogRef,
    private readonly confirmDialog: ConfirmDialogService,
    private readonly screenshotService: ScreenshotService,
    private readonly statistic: ServiceDeskStatisticService,
    private readonly popupService: PopupService,
  ) {
    super(dialog);
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.screenshotService.subscribePaste(this.onImagePaste);
    this.attachmentRestrictions = this.params.attachmentRestrictions;
    this.required = this.params.required;
    this.attachmentControl = new UploadFileControl(this.params);
    this.validate();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.screenshotService.unsubscribePaste(this.onImagePaste);
  }

  public onSubmitClick(): void {
    this.close({ files: this.attachmentControl.value.allFiles });
  }

  public async onCancelClick(): Promise<void> {
    const confirmCancel = await this.confirmDialog.confirmDialog();

    if (confirmCancel) {
      this.close();
    }
  }

  private validate(): void {
    this.attachmentControl.addValidators([
      requiredValidator,
      filesAcceptableFormatValidator(this.attachmentRestrictions.allowedExtensions),
      filesSizeValidator(this.attachmentRestrictions.maxFileSize),
    ]);

    this.attachmentControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  private onImagePaste = async (file: File): Promise<void> => {
    await this.showAddScreenshotPopup(file);
  };

  private async showAddScreenshotPopup(file: File): Promise<void> {
    const componentReference = this.popupService.createContent(ServiceDeskAddScreenshotPopupComponent);
    const popupSettings = ServiceDeskAddScreenshotPopupComponent.settings;

    await componentReference.instance.setImage(file);

    componentReference.instance.completed.subscribe((data: AddScreenshotResult) => this.addScreenshot(data));

    this.popupService.show(popupSettings, componentReference);
  }

  private async addScreenshot(data: AddScreenshotResult): Promise<void> {
    if (!data) {
      return;
    }

    const file = new File([data.image], data.fileName);

    this.statistic.ticketScreenshotAdded(null);
    this.files.push(file);
    this.files = [...this.files];
    // this.changingFiles.next(true);
  }
}
```

I need to move those methods : `onImagePaste`, `showAddScreenshotPopup`, `addScreenshot` inside Service.

But main problem, how I can  return file, to add it to array, like I do it here?

```
 this.files.push(file);
    this.files = [...this.files];
```

Comment: Also move the `files` array to the service?